# How to share array index between threads in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, race-condition

I have the following code:

```
def task1():
    for url in splitarr[0]:
        print(url) #these are supposed to be scrape_induvidual_page() . print is just for debugging
def task2():
    for url in splitarr[1]:
        print(url)
def task3():
    for url in splitarr[2]:
        print(url)
def task4():
    for url in splitarr[3]:
        print(url)
def task5():
    for url in splitarr[4]:
        print(url)
def task6():
    for url in splitarr[5]:
        print(url)
def task7():
    for url in splitarr[6]:
        print(url)     
def task8():
    for url in splitarr[7]:
        print(url)   

splitarr=np.array_split(urllist, 8)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=task1, name='t1') 
t2 = threading.Thread(target=task2, name='t2')   
t3 = threading.Thread(target=task3, name='t3')
t4 = threading.Thread(target=task4, name='t4') 
t5 = threading.Thread(target=task5, name='t5')
t6 = threading.Thread(target=task6, name='t6')
t7 = threading.Thread(target=task7, name='t7')
t8 = threading.Thread(target=task8, name='t8')

t1.start() 
t2.start()
t3.start() 
t4.start() 
t5.start()
t6.start() 
t7.start()
t8.start() 

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
t4.join()
t5.join()
t6.join()
t7.join() 
t8.join()
```

And it does have the desired output without duplicates or anything

```
https://kickasstorrents.to/big-buck-bunny-1080p-h264-aac-5-1-tntvillage-t115783.html
https://kickasstorrents.to/big-buck-bunny-4k-uhd-hfr-60fps-eng-flac-webdl-2160p-x264-zmachine-t1041079.html
https://kickasstorrents.to/big-buck-bunny-4k-uhd-hfr-60-fps-flac-webrip-2160p-x265-zmachine-t1041689.html
https://kickasstorrents.to/big-buck-bunny-2008-720p-bluray-x264-don-no-rars-t11623.html
https://kickasstorrents.to/tkillaahh-big-buck-bunny-dvd-720p-2lions-team-t87503.html
https://kickasstorrents.to/big-buck-bunny-2008-720p-bluray-nhd-x264-nhanc3-t127050.html
https://kickasstorrents.to/big-buck-bunny-2008-brrip-720p-x264-mitzep-t172753.html
```

However, I feel like the code is a bit redundant with all the repeated **def taskx():**
So I attempted to compact the code down by using a single task:

```
x=0
def task1():
    global x
    for url in splitarr[x]:
        print(url)
        x=x+1
t1 = threading.Thread(target=task1, name='t1') 
t2 = threading.Thread(target=task1, name='t2')   
t3 = threading.Thread(target=task1, name='t3')
t4 = threading.Thread(target=task1, name='t4') 
t5 = threading.Thread(target=task1, name='t5')
t6 = threading.Thread(target=task1, name='t6')
t7 = threading.Thread(target=task1, name='t7')
t8 = threading.Thread(target=task1, name='t8')

t1.start() 
t2.start()
t3.start() 
t4.start() 
t5.start()
t6.start() 
t7.start()
t8.start() 

t1.join()
t2.join()
t3.join()
t4.join()
t5.join()
t6.join()
t7.join() 
t8.join()
```

However, this gives undesired output with duplicates:

```
https://kickasstorrents.to/big-buck-bunny-1080p-h264-aac-5-1-tntvillage-t115783.html
https://kickasstorrents.to/big-buck-bunny-1080p-h264-aac-5-1-tntvillage-t115783.html
https://kickasstorrents.to/big-buck-bunny-4k-uhd-hfr-60-fps-flac-webrip-2160p-x265-zmachine-t1041689.html
https://kickasstorrents.to/big-buck-bunny-2008-720p-bluray-x264-don-no-rars-t11623.html
https://kickasstorrents.to/big-buck-bunny-2008-720p-bluray-x264-don-no-rars-t11623.html
https://kickasstorrents.to/tkillaahh-big-buck-bunny-dvd-720p-2lions-team-t87503.html
https://kickasstorrents.to/big-buck-bunny-2008-brrip-720p-x264-mitzep-t172753.html
https://kickasstorrents.to/big-buck-bunny-2008-brrip-720p-x264-mitzep-t172753.html
```

How do I make the x increment properly in a program with multiple threads?

Comment: You can send parameters to the function executed in a thread. Use this to send the index.

Comment: Have you tried using passing the list index as the function argument?  like `def taskx(x):` and then while setting the target, you can manually pass the argument `x` in the target for `threading.Thread` using `partial` from functools ? You are probably getting duplicates because you are using a global variable ang the time for each thread to finish is different.

Comment: Ah thanks, passing index as parameter  worked. I have updated the answer

Comment: You should find out how lists and loops work. They would make your code less repetitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for url in splitarr[x]:` creates an iterator for the sequence in `splitarr[x]`. It doesn't matter that you increment x later - the iterator is already built. Since you have a print in there, its very likely that all of the threads will grab `x` when its still zero and iterate the same sequence.

One solution is to pass incrementing values to task1 via the `args` argument in `threading.Thread`. But a thread pool is even easier.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

# generate test array
splitarr = []
for i in range(8):
    splitarr.append([f"url_{i}_{j}" for j in range(4)])

def task(splitarr_column):
    for url in splitarr_column:
        print(url)

with ThreadPool(len(splitarr)) as pool:
    result = pool.map(task, splitarr)
```

In this example, `len(splitarr)` is used to create one thread per sequence in `splitarr`. Then each of those sequences is mapped to the `task` function. Since we created the right number of threads to handle all of the sequences, they all run at once. When the map completes, the `with` clause exits and the pool is closed, terminating the threads.